# Where to use `ApplicativeError` instead of `Either`?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, applicative, cats-effect

There is `ApplicativeError[F,E]` + `F[A]` and there is `Either[E, A]`. Both convey the message that the function could fail with an `E` or succeed with an `A` but I'm not sure about the different message they convey to the client about the intended way of handling the error :

```
def f1[F[_]: Applicative[F]]: F[Either[E, A]]
def f2[F[_]: ApplicativeError[F,E]]: F[A]
```

I understand `f1` means: client is responsible for error handling. But what does `f2` mean to the client about how to handle the error ?

Answer (score 6):

`ApplicativeError[F, E]` assumes that the type of `E` is somehow encoded in `F` and you could create instance of `ApplicativeError[F, E]` only because for this particular `F` it makes sense to have error `E`. Examples:

- `ApplicativeError[Task, Throwable]` - `Task` uses `Throwable` as an error channel so it makes sense to expose `Throwable` as error algebra. As a matter of the fact `Sync[F]` from Cats Effect implements `MonadError[F, Throwable]`, which in turns implement `ApplicativeError[F, Throwable]` - many type classes of Cats Effect assume that you only deal with `Throwable`
- `ApplicativeError[Task[Either[E, *]], E]` - in such combinations you will have `E` both in type `F`'s specific definition as well as in `E` parameter - this is typical for all kind of bifunctors: `Task[Either[E, *]]`, `EitherT[Task, E, *]`, ZIO's `IO[E, A]`, and so on

The interface `ApplicativeError[F, E]` doesn't handle error on its own. But it  exposes methods:

- `raiseError[A](e: E): F[A]` - which creates an error
- `handleErrorWith[A](fa: F[A])(f: (E) ⇒ F[A]): F[A]` - which handled it

so that you could tell it how to handle it.

Both works without assuming anything about the nature of error and F other that it is `Applicative` which can fail. If you only use `F` and type classes, you can use these methods to recover from error. And if you know the exact type of `F` on call site (because it is hardcoded to `Task`, `IO`, `Coeval`, etc) you can use recovery method directly.

The main difference is that result `F[Either[E, A]]` doesn't tell the caller that `E` should be treated as a failure. `F[A]` tells that there could be only `A` successful value. Additionally one requires `Applicative` while the other `ApplicativeError`, so there is difference in "power" required to create a value - if you see `ApplicativeError` even though there is no `E` in result you can assume that method might fail because it requires more powerful type class.

But of course it is not set in stone and it is mainly about expressing intentions, because everywhere you have `F[A]` you can convert to and from `F[Either[E, A]]` using `ApplicativeError[F, E]` (there are even methods for it like `attempt[A](fa: F[A]): F[Either[E, A]]` or `fromEither[A](x: Either[E, A]): F[A]`). So on one part of your application you can have `F[A]` with `E` algebra, but then there is that one pure function that uses `Either[E, A] => B` which you would like to use - then you could convert, map, and if necessary convert back.

TL;DR it is mainly about expressing intent as both are "morally" equal.